# is it easy to convert java se to a Spring MVC? and should I do it?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a java SE web application that is divided in layers. each database table has its own class and I write manually the updates, inserts and deletes in JDBC.

Is it easy to migrate my project to Spring to benefit from JPA ?
And should I do it? A key objective of the project is to be totally flexible and easy to develop, and it is right now so what are the benefits of migrating.

Thank you

Comment: I never heard of java SE web application. It is Java EE. Correct your problem

Comment: are you talking about a desktop app (swing ..) to be converted to web-app using spring mvc ?

Comment: no no its a web application, i simply divided the layers myself, with no j2ee framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it :)

Unless there's a compelling reason, I wouldn't re-write your existing app.

If, however, you're re-writing a desktop Swing ("thick client") application to be a web app, that alone might be sufficient justification to invest in the learning curve to try Spring.

IMHO...

Comment: no my application is web based, JSP. I'm using classes as entities, and backing beans. I just thought if i benefit from something if i migrate to spring

Comment: Hi - it doesn't really sound like it.  Which, of course, is a Good Thing :)  IMHO...